# Column with different pointers Parse.Com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I have an application which uses Parse to save objects on MongoDB. On my db, I have a class which has a column that should be a pointer to make my job easier. But I have a problem, this column should hold a pointer for differents classes. Parse doesn't allow me to do that because it takes the first pointer saved as the type of that column.

Does anyone have an idea about how I can work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a pointer to two different classes in the same column. If you really need to do this, then you could create a new class that has fields for each of the possible pointer types.

So for example if you have a `User` and you need a pointer to either `Car` or `Boat`, then you could make a new class called `Vehicle` that has pointers to both `Car` and `Boat`. And then make the `User` just have one pointer to `Vehicle`.

That's a silly example, but it could technically work. How different are the classes that you need to point to from the same column? It's probably best practice if you consolidate them or find a different approach, but having a "holder" object that contains pointers to all possible values is one way you could essentially accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did think about this approach of creating a class that have the others pointers but the problem is that this new class will have only one pointer at a time because I don't use both at the same time.  

The classes are completely different, I can't merge them. 

Anyways, thanks for the answer